# What's the word or phrase for the situation in which you know about someone's secret and that gives you an advantage over them?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What's the word or phrase for the situation in which you know about someone's secret and that gives you an advantage over them?

For example, when a child knows that his father has done something wrong and thus takes advantage of it (by threatening that he would tell the truth to his mother or so).

Comment: "So you can ask them what you want"? That seems oddly specific—but I also don't understand it.

Comment: @JasonBassford, You're right! I just edited my question.

Comment: Are you talking about just having an advantage (in which case it could be something like *leverage*)—or actually using it? (If using it, you could be describing *extortion*, *blackmail*, or simply *coercion*, depending on the particular context.) Or are you still thinking of something different than those type of things?

Comment: @JasonBassford, "leverage" seems fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comments under the question, this is asking for a term to describe the knowledge of the secret itself, and how it can be used. (In short, a better word than just *advantage*.)

To have knowledge of a secret that *could* be used against somebody is to have [**leverage**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leverage) over them:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **2** : POWER, EFFECTIVENESS
>   // trying to gain more political *leverage*
>   // The union's size gave it *leverage* in the labor contract negotiations.
>   // The player's popularity has given him a great deal of *leverage* with the owners of the team.

In the example in the question:

> Knowing an embarrassing secret, a child has *leverage* over his father.

---

In a more informal sense, it could also be said that you have [**dirt**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dirt) on them:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>    **3 e** : embarrassing or incriminating information
>   // trying to dig up *dirt* on her political rivals

---

Of course, the two words are not mutually exclusive:

> Having dug up *dirt* on him, she had *leverage* over him.

---

Once all of this is in place and actually used, it would then be described as *blackmail*, *extortion*, or just *coercion*, depending on the context.

Answer (score 0):

'Leverage' is probably the most appropriate but you could say that the secret knowledge is your 'ace in the hole'.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! Right now this is a short answer. It gives a "what," but doesn't explain why that's the case or how others can assess that it's correct. I suggest including a source and/or more explanation to show why your answer is the best.